# How to generate django ORM code for below query?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I want to generate ORM code for below query.

My Models :

```
class tbl2(models.models):
    code1 = models.CharField()

class tbl1(model.models):
    x = models.CharField()
    y1 = models.ForeignKey(tbl2)
    y2 = models.ForeignKey(tbl2)
    amount = models.integerField()
```

Query

```
select p1.x, sum(p1.amount) from tbl1 p1, 
          tbl1 p2
          where p2.y1 = p1.referred_by_id 
          group by p1.x;
```

Comment: p1 does not have a "email" attribute. I believe you switched the tables name and forgot something in your sql.

Comment: @furins Thnx i changed it.

Comment: I tried to correct it a little bit more. I do not get the point of declaring p1.y1 = p2.referred_by_id since p2 is never used and there is no way to get an instance of it (=the ID)

Comment: @furins Actually i want to do self join.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I do not really understand your query, how it relates to your class definitions and in particular how can you assure that the ID of instances of `tbl1` can match the ID of instances of **class** `tbl2`. Maybe there is something you may add to your question to improve it? What I observe is that `p2.y1` is referring to instances of **class** `tbl2` not **tbl1** so this is not self-referring.

However, simply translating your SQL code into something that may run on django gives the following code:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models import F

tbl1.objects.filter(y1__id=F('id')).values('x').annotate(sum_amount=Sum('amount'))
```

but I believe you meant something different in your class definition, maybe:

```
class tbl1(model.models):
    x = models.CharField()
    y1 = models.ForeignKey(self)
    y2 = models.ForeignKey(self)
    amount = models.integerField()
```

the Queryset I've provided works also in this second case.

reference for aggregation classes: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#topics-db-aggregation

reference for F() function:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/queries/#django.db.models.F

reference for self-reference in models:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

---

**SIDE NOTE: class names should be [Capitalized](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)**